# Access HTTP_REFERER in Nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, config, http-referer

I have edited my `fastcgi.conf` file and added the following in an attempt to access the `$http_referer`: `fastcgi_param  HTTP_REFERER  $http_referer;`.

After doing so I made sure to reload my `php-fpm`.

In this example I'm attempting to stop any domain with `google` in it from refering to my domain, but when I try to restart my nginx I get the error: `Invalid Condition: "$http_referer"`.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server.domain;
  if($http_referer != "") {
    if ($http_referer ~* (google)) {
      return $http_referer;
    }
  }
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default deferred;
  root /var/www/html;
  server_name server.domain;
  if($http_referer != "") {
    if ($http_referer ~* (google)) {
      return $http_referer;
    }
  }    
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;";
}
```

My thoughts are either I did not add the $http_referer into the fastcgi.conf correctly or maybe I added it to the wrong file so it didn't load... or I possibly did not include the fastcgi_params correctly.

Additionally, maybe I need to install a module ontop of nginx, but I'm not sure how to add them.

Comment: Try using Google [*oh the irony*] before posting your question. [See this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/519826/nginx-and-http-referer).

Comment: @Martin I did google plenty before having asked this question.. and I found multiple instances where someone used $http_referer. I realize that it's not always set, that's why I am checking if it's empty. I don't see why I am getting `Invalid Condition`.

I even setup a php script on my index of the https server to redirect back if the referrer includes google and it does work.

Comment: Would `invalid condition` be returned if the var is empty? the answer I reference (and wider general PHP knowledge) states that the referer value is by no means required and can often be unset or invalid. It's not a good way of tracking, unfortunately

Comment: also add the details in your comment into your question, which other questions did you look at, why did they not help you?